# Add tags to CSV file with awk

Tags: xml, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with 321 entries and this is the header:

- BILLING_NAME
- CONSUMER_ID
- BILLING_ADDRESS1
- BILLING_CITY
- BILLING_STATE
- BILLING_ZIP
- BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER
- ACH_ACCOUNT_NUMBER

I'd like to insert the xml tag around each entry:

```
<billingName>Stackoverflow</billingname> <consumerID>4454</consumerID> etc
```

All the way through this file. These fields above and a few others not mentioned will be used to make a curl request to add an account on file via API, so after I have all the necessary tags, I can create sequential xml requests.

I've been able to separate out all the data above with awk and make 8 different files, but I don't know how to join them together.

The field separator in the CSV is a comma (,) and unfortunately, cut didn't do a perfect job so there will probably be some records I need to manually process.

I'm pretty sure this can be done with just awk but I don't exactly know how I would loop it for all records.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**

One final modification would make all of this work perfect.

```
awk -F, '{
filename = $2
$1 = "<api-request>";
$2 = "<verification>";
$3 = "<merchantId>11</merchantId>";
$4 = "<merchantKey>key</merchantKey>";
$5 = "</verification>";
$6 = "<command>add-ach-onfile</command>";
$7 = "<request>";
$8 = "<billingName>"$8"</billingName>";
$9 = "<customerId>"$9"</customerId>";
$10 = "<billingAddress1>"$10"</billingAddress1>";
$11 = "<billingCity>"$11"</billingCity>";
$12 = "<billingState>"$12"</billingState>";
$13 = "<billingZip>"$13"</billingZip>";
$14 = "<bankRoutingNumber>"$14"</bankRoutingNumber>";
$15 = "<achAccountNumber>"$15"</achAccountNumber>";
$16 = "</request>";
$17 = "</api-request>";
print > filename
}' 2export.csv
```

So I know $8-$15 work on their own but I'd like to add in $1-7, $16 & 17 so the api request will be completed.

```
<api-request> <verification> <merchantId>11</merchantId> <merchantKey>key</merchantKey> </verification> <command>add-ach-onfile</command> <request> <billingName>016114849</billingName> <customerId></customerId> <billingAddress1></billingAddress1> <billingCity></billingCity> <billingState></billingState> <billingZip></billingZip> <bankRoutingNumber></bankRoutingNumber> <achAccountNumber></achAccountNumber> </request> </api-request>
```

Above shows that the NEW tags work but the existing tags don't contain data. I'm quite sure I just need to change the contents of $8-15 to have it read from my 2export.csv file and not from standard input but all my attempts are not working.

Comment: `stackover flow,4544,1000 W Any Street,Salt Lake City,UT,84101,122874015,874`

`stack exchange,254870,8080 N Broadford Avenue,Santa Cruz,CA,95065,825643792,9044564351298`

The data can be whatever you like it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very easily accomplish it using awk

```
$ awk -F, '{
 $1 = "<billing_name>"$1"</billing_name>";
 $2 = "<consumer_id>"$2"</consumer_id>";
 $3 = "<billing_address1>"$3"</billing_address1>";
 $4 = "<billing_city>"$4"</billing_city>";
 $5 = "<billing_state>"$5"</billing_state>";
 $6 = "<billing_zip>"$6"</billing_zip>";
 $7 = "<bank_routing_number>"$7"</bank_routing_number>";
 $8 = "<ach_account_number>"$8"</ach_account_number>";
 }1' test
```

will produce an output like

```
<billing_name>stackoverflow</billing_name> <consumer_id>4454</consumer_id> etc
```

**EDIT**

Split rows to different files

```
$ awk -F, '{
     filename = $1
     $1 = "<billing_name>"$1"</billing_name>";
     $2 = "<consumer_id>"$2"</consumer_id>";
     $3 = "<billing_address1>"$3"</billing_address1>";
     $4 = "<billing_city>"$4"</billing_city>";
     $5 = "<billing_state>"$5"</billing_state>";
     $6 = "<billing_zip>"$6"</billing_zip>";
     $7 = "<bank_routing_number>"$7"</bank_routing_number>";
     $8 = "<ach_account_number>"$8"</ach_account_number>";

     print > filename
     }' test
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I knew I was very close when I was splitting up the files.

Now any ideas how I was separate each line into its own file with a sequential name?

Comment: you can use a redirect within the awk for example `print "<billing_name>"$1"</billing_name>" > billing_namefile`

Comment: Hello nu11p01n73R, sorry, not redirect each tag to a file but each row/line to its own file.

So stackoverflow would be in its own file and so would stack exchange.

Comment: Hello nu11p01n73R! That's exactly correct on both!

So the only difference is the filename = $1 and print $0 > filename

Pretty clever! 

Thanks so much for the assistance with this.

Comment: You can skip the  `$0` in `print $0`, just `print` is enough.

Comment: @Jotne I didn't knew that !! Thank you . Added in the answer :)